# How to show results after selecting a product in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a list of products that is shown as a table and I want to show more information  (make a call to another api) about a certain product on a modal when the product row is clicked. The modal is now working and the modal is showing up when the row is clicked but I'm not sure how to implement the logic of making another call to another api/endpoint and show the info about right product when it is clicked. Where should I make the other api call? Should I have another state for the other api in the constructor and then fetch in ComponentDidMount()?

```
//Modal.js

import React from "react";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

 export default function Modal() {
   return (
     <div className="modalContainer">
      <Table responsive="true" size="sm" striped bordered hover>
       <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Own Product</th>
          <th>Competitors Products</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>
     </Table>
     <Button onClick={props.closeButton} size="sm" variant="outline- 
     secondary">
       Close
     </Button>
  </div>
 ); 
}


//ProductTable.js

 export default class TableView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    products: [],
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    modalOpen: false,
    selectedProduct: {}
  };
}

 toggleModal = product => {
  this.setState({ selectedProduct: product });
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    modalOpen: !prevState.modalOpen
 }));
};

fetchProducts() {
  axios
   .get(
    "some api"
)
.then(res => {
console.log(res);
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      products: res.data
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.fetchProducts();
}

render() {
  let { isLoaded, products } = this.state; 

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <Loading />;
  } else {
    return (
     <div className="tableContainer">
      {this.props.rows}

      <Table responsive="true" size="sm" striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Match ID</th>
            <th>Match Name</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Match Score</th>
            <th>Match Price</th>
            <th>Match State</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {products &&
            products.map(product => (
              //use filter instead to show only the matched ones
              <tr
                key={product.id}
                onClick={() => this.toggleModal(product)}
              >
                <td>{product.id}</td>
                <td>{product.matches[0].id}</td>
                <td>{product.matches[0].name}</td>
                <td>{product.matches[0].specifications.brand}</td>
                <td>{Math.round(product.matches[0].score)}</td>
                <td>{product.matches[0].price}</td>
                <td>{product.matches[0].matchLabel}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          {this.state.modalOpen ? (
            <Modal
              product={this.state.selectedProduct}
              closeButton={this.toggleModal}
            />
          ) : null}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
   );
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: make another api call in same function where you clicked because with the help of that clicked item you are calling another api. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple approaches for this.

1. You can maintain another state variable. And put the api call in toggleModal, like below:

Define another state variable in your state say productInfo.

```
this.state = {
    products: [],
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    modalOpen: false,
    selectedProduct: {},
    productInfo: null
};
```

Then in toggleModal, whenever toggleModal is setting state, you need to check if modalOpen is true, then make an apiCall. I assume apiCall is an endpoint here which returns product info.

```
toggleModal = product => {
this.setState({ selectedProduct: product });
this.setState(prevState => ({modalOpen: !prevState.modalOpen}), () => {
    if (this.state.modalOpen) {
        //Make an api call
        fetch(apiCall).then(res => {
            this.setState({productInfo: res.data });
        });
    }
 });
};
```

Pass the same state in Modal as props:

```
<Modal
    product={this.state.selectedProduct}
    closeButton={this.toggleModal}
    productInfo={this.state.productInfo}
    />
```

Or,

2. Define Modal as a class, define state of Modal and use life cycle methods of  Modal, like componentDidMount(), make an api call there and display the details.